# Edge Extension Native Messaging: Dealing with UWP message size limit

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge-extension

I am developing an extension for Edge where I need to send more than 1MB of data to the extension from UWP.

I have chunked the data to be less than 1MB and tried to send reply multiple times something like below

```
private async void OnAppServiceRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args) {
  AppServiceDeferral messageDeferral = args.GetDeferral();

  // This is to be replaced with enumerator
   for (int i = 0; i < number_of_chunks; i++) {
      // construct reply identifying the chunk number and termination
       await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(reply);
   }
   messageDeferral.Complete();

}
```

The app service is cancelled when sending the second response in the above loop. It seems like a response can be sent only if there is a corresponding request. Can someone confirm this?

Are there any alternative mechanisms in UWP to send the data asynchronously without a request?

Another option I can think of is to have the chunking logic moved to the background and it doesn't feel right.

FWIW, Chrome & Firefox doesn't have such limitation and I am able to send messages to stdout asynchronously.

**Update#1:** Peter, I am afraid I get the same error "A method was called at an unexpected time" for the second sendReply. I tried the following and hope this is what you meant.

```
private async void OnAppServiceRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args) {

  // This is to be replaced with enumerator
   for (int i = 0; i < number_of_chunks; i++) {
      // construct reply identifying the chunk number and termination
      AppServiceDeferral messageDeferral = args.GetDeferral();
      await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(reply);
      messageDeferral.Complete();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi sumo, seems I am facing the same issue. Have you found a solution that you could share?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `args.GetDeferral()` in order to avoid having your connection torn down at the first suspension call (`await`). Then you need to call `Complete()` on the deferral once your work is done.